# Does `continued_fraction(d)` for a quadratic field element d compute whole preperiod and period eagerly?

Tags: sage

New to sage, toying with continued fractions. I noticed that my code experiences performance degradation when I use `continued_fraction(d)`, where d is represented as a `QuadraticField` element, and the CF has long period (in the thousands). There is no slowness if the same value is represented as a regular `sage.symbolic.expression.Expression`.

Does sage compute the preperiod and period eagerly for elements of quadratic fields? Am I better off not using QuadraticField values if all I need is a constant number of first partial quotients regardless of period length?